# Regarding FoldLeft with list and map in scala

Tags: scala

I have a list of strings as json messages and i need to write to object from json using json4s.After parsing i need to store the object and objects attribute as key in a Map.
Using **var** approach i am able to do that .But i do not want to use var and would like to use foldLeft to do the same.

#### Definition of class:

```
case class Definition
{
   name:String,
   status:String
}
```

#### sample json:

```
{"name":"test",
"status":"Enabled"
}
```

Using json4s read api i am getting the object as below.

```
Definition(test,Enabled)
```

i will get lit objects like above.From this list i need to create a map and need to store object.name as key and object as value.

Looking for optimized approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// define case class
case class Definition(name: String, status: String)

// read objects from json
// i use test data to simplify example
val list = List(
  Definition("name1", "status1"),
  Definition("name2", "status2"),
  Definition("name3", "status3")
)

// transform list to map
list.map(d => d.name -> d).toMap
```

To convert from json you can use:

```
val objectList = definitionList
  .foldLeft(List.empty[Definition])((listObject,result) => listObject :+ read[Definition](result))
```

or:

```
definitionList.map(read[Definition])
```

Comment: The second element of the tuple should be `d`, not `d.status`.

Comment: i got stuck with read api of json4s to convert from json to object.Trying with -->  val objectList = definitionList.foldLeft(List.empty[Definition])((listObject,result) => listObject+(read[Definition](result)))   but getting compilation issue. basically i am converting list of json strings to list of definition objects

Comment: i am getting json as a string and trying to convert that json to definition object using read API of json4s

Comment: @SergeyLagutin Thanks a lot.it is working. BTW could you explain me the difference between + and +: .

Comment: @user1668653 `:+` create new list which contains all elements of this list and new element. Method `+` is undefined.